# Define a function outside a class and call the function using action or filter hook

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

Hi Currently i am developing a sub plugin for my own main plugin. Please see the main plugin code below

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        function test1()
        {
            echo 'hii- test1';
        }
        $this->autoload_function();
    }

    function autoload_function()
    {
        $my_array = array(
            "test1"
        );

        foreach ($my_array as $my_function)
        {
            call_user_func($my_function);
        }

    }

}

$var = new MyClass();

?>
```

**My sub plugin need to add more values to $my_array and i am allowed to use do_action or apply_filtere in main plugin.**

I added  `apply_filters`, so that i can modify the $my_array in my sub plugin.

**my-class.php**

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        function test1()
        {
            echo 'hii- test1';
        }
        $this->autoload_function();
    }

    function autoload_function()
    {
        $my_array = array(
            "test1"
        );

        apply_filters('modify_array', $my_array);
        foreach ($my_array as $my_function)
        {
            call_user_func($my_function);
        }

    }

}

$var = new MyClass();

?>
```

In my sub plugin i checked the filter and i can see that filter is working perfectly so that i can modify the value of $my_array in my sub plugin.

**my-newpage.php**

```
add_filter ('modify_array', 'modify_array_function', 0);


function modify_array_function($my_array){
 array_push($my_array, 'test2')
}
```

Here i can see that new value is added to array but now i have to define test2 function inside my sub plugin .

```
function test2(){
 echo 'hii- test2';
}
```

When i write test2 function in my sub plugin i am getting below error .

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
> class **'MyClass' does not have a method**
> **'test2'**

Now how can i solve this ? Do i need to add more action or filters in the sub plugin .

> **The issue is due to  `call_user_func('test2');`  is called inside **my-class.php**  but the test2 function is defined outside mycalss. It is defined inside my sub plugin.**

Please help to solve this error.

Comment: Is `test2` a member function of  your class?  Can't you just make it a user defined function, and call it from anywhere then?

Comment: Are you sure the main method is working? It should fail with "expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'test1' not found" already, see [this online example](https://3v4l.org/0ab13).

Comment: @kero thanks for checking. I have modified my code. please see this https://3v4l.org/eBnNH

Comment: @SallyCJ While I like the metaphor, [it certainly isn't true for PHP](https://3v4l.org/pokP6).

Comment: @kero thanks, and yes, because your [`foo()`](https://3v4l.org/pokP6) function was defined in the same scope, and that's what I meant by "be defined before being called".. Anyway, I think I have misunderstood OP, hence I deleted all my previous comments. And I've posted an answer, so if you noticed anything (wrong), let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I presumed your sub plugin loads after the main one, right?

> Here i can see that new value is added to array but now i have to define test2 function inside my sub plugin

If you're certain `test2` successfully added to the array and that `test2` was being called from `MyClass::autoload_function()`, then you can *try using an early hook **like [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)** to define `test2`*, like so:

```php
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My Sub Plugin */

// Defines the test2() function.
function my_define_test2() {
    function test2(){
        echo 'hii- test2';
    }
}

// Now hook on init to ensure test2() is defined before your main plugin
// is loaded.
add_action( 'init', 'my_define_test2', 1 );

// And then add test2() to $my_array (that you defined in the main plugin).
add_filter( 'modify_array', 'modify_array_function' );
function modify_array_function( $my_array ) {
    array_push( $my_array, 'test2' );
    return $my_array; // remember, filters must always return something =)
}
```

If however `MyClass` is instantiated immediately when WordPress loads the plugin, i.e. something like so, then I don't think it's possible for you to define `test2` before `MyClass` is instantiated. Unless maybe, if you use a [Must Use](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) plugin.

```php
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My Main Plugin */

class MyClass { ... }

$var = new MyClass();
```